# image not vertical-align middle div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to inset the image in to the div but it's not align middle.

Can you please help me !

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; flaot:left; margin:0; padding:0;"><img src="image.png" width="100" height="100" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="image.png" width="100" height="100" />
```

Comment: vertical-align:middle vill only make it aligned middle compared to other inline elements inside the <div>, so that will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative margins to achieve this, when you know the heights involved:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin:0; padding:0;"><img src="image.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="margin-top: -50px" /></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know all sizes (div and img) you can use something like that: [tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/vrUv9i8w)

CSS:

```
#content{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 200px;
}

#content img{
    vertical-align: middle;      
}
​
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/120/120" width="100" height="100" />
</div>​
```

Or one more version: [tinkerbin](http://tinkerbin.com/LpfINtHS)

CSS:

```
#content{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#content img{
   position: relative;
   top: 50%;
   margin-top: -50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally used this and it works...

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; margin:0; padding:0; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><img src="image.png" width="100" height="100" /></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey now used to `Dispaly:table-cell` properties and **remove** `float:left;` in your **css**

As like this

**css**

```
.parent{
  width:200px; 
  height:200px;
 text-align:center;
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  margin:0; padding:0;
  background:red;
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="parent">
  <img src="http://outgrow.me/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/ramos-305x203.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
</div>
```

Live demo http://tinkerbin.com/4IU9UvR9